# Error: Invalid XML: jquery or convert multiple root into multiple variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to add some dynamic tag into my xml

and for that i am using this code

```
var valuetoadd=$.parseXML("<vpbasicComment><commentId>23</commentId></vpbasicComment><vpbasicComment><commentId>26</commentId></vpbasicComment>");

$(valuetoadd).appendTo(MYsourcexml);
```

and give me error how i am able to add this tags into my xml.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a root element in your xml, you need to add one.

```
<root>
    <vpbasicComment>
        <commentId>23</commentId>
    </vpbasicComment>
    <vpbasicComment>
        <commentId>26</commentId>
    </vpbasicComment>
</root>
```

Comment: but i want to add this in xml

Comment: and server dont expect root as element in xml.

Comment: In that case you don't need to parse the xml, just insert it as a string.

Comment: without parse appendto convert all character to lowercase